# Scala type variance on Lower bounds

Tags: scala, covariance

In Programming in Scala 2nd Edition in section 19.5 in following example

```
class Queue[+T] (private val leading: List[T],
      private val trailing: List[T] ) {
    def enqueue[U >: T](x: U) =
      new Queue[U](leading, x :: trailing) // ...
}
```

`T` should end up at negative position like below

```
def enqueue[U- >: T-](x: U-) =
          new Queue[U](leading, x :: trailing) // ...
```

But the book mentions that there are 2 flips

> Technically, what happens is a flip occurs for lower bounds. The type parameter U is in a negative position (1 flip), while the lower bound (>: T) is in a positive position (2 flips).

How 2 flips occur here?

Answer (score 1):

In `enqueue`, `T` is *not* a type parameter, but a **reference to a type member of the outer context.** Therefore it is not correct to say "`T` should end up at negative position".

Perhaps you could think of the reference to `T` as the lower bound of `U` as a "method call that yields `T`", only it's a "type call", so `T` is sort of in a "return type" or covariant position.

The following sentence is important:

> Intuitively, if `T` is a more specific type than expected (for example, `Apple` instead of `Fruit`), a call to append will still work, because `U` (`Fruit`) will still be a supertype of `T` (`Apple`).

Comment: if it is a type call ..does the flip of classification occurs? I couldn't  understand/get how 2 flips occurs for T

Comment: @Pushparaj these "flips" are nothing but an internal mechanism in the compiler I suppose. Perhaps it's one flip for entering a method declaration and the other for referring to a type constructor parameter.